# Adapting app architecture for heroku platform

Tags: database, heroku, architecture

It's time to deploy my app. on heroku and I should adapt the architecture of my application to the norms imposed by heroku. Locally, I keep my database credentials in a config file, but on heroku I have to extract them from an environment variable. So, If I want an universal interface for my application I need to get rid of that config file. Maybe I can create a similar environment variable locally, or I can keep that config file with database credentials only in the development branch.
What would be the best approach for this problem. In general, in production, where do you keep database credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your app to use environment variables for configuration - ie. externalise your configuration - then it should work equally well locally and on Heroku.

Heroku's config vars are simply made available as environment variables when running on Heroku.

You can do the same thing locally if you use [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/).

ie if you start your app with `foreman start web` then it will take all the name/value pairs in a local `.env` file, and map them to environment variables.